# Subset pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe, subset

I have a pandas dataframe which has following columns: `cust_email, transaction_id, transaction_timestamp`

I want to subset the pandas dataframe and include only those email ids which have only one transaction (i.e only one `transaction_id, transaction_timestamp` for a `cust_email`)

Comment: can u show your code?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop_duplicates` and set parameter `keep` to `False`. If you want to drop duplicates by a specific column you can use the `subset` parameter:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset="cust_email", keep=False)
```

For example

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame()
data["col1"] = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e"]
data["col2"] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

print(data)
print()
data.drop_duplicates(subset="col1", keep=False)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html